# OpenShift repo not included in path

Tags: openshift, django-1.7, paas

I started a Django 1.7 OpenShift instance. When I have python print all of the paths from `sys.path` I do not see `OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` (`/var/lib/openshift/xxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo`).

When I use `https://github.com/jfmatth/openshift-django17` to create a project I do see `OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR` in the path.

Looking through the example app above I don't see anywhere that this is specifically added to the path. What am I missing?

To clarify:
I have to add the following to my wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys
ON_PASS = 'OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR' in os.environ
if ON_PASS:
    x = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'mysite'))
    sys.path.insert(1, x)
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR is not in my path as I would expect. When I used the example git above, I did not have to add anything to the path.

Comment: Can you give some more information on what exactly you are trying to do and why you need that directory on your PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to be caused by trying to use the standard file structure layout that django produces when you use startproject. Openshift appears to need a flatter file structure. As soon as I moved wsgi up to a sibling of mysite it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A little while back I had issues with some of the pre-configured OpenShift environment variables not appearing until I restarted my application.

For what its worth, I started up a brand new Django gear, printed the environment variables to the application log, and verified that I do see OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR (and all other env vars) properly.